# Replace twig templates with blade

Tags: php, laravel, payum

Is there a way to replace the standard templates with blade ones? I'm using payum with the payum-laravel-package and klarna-checkout gateway.

I've come to the point where i need to replace the template for AuthorizeAction. I noticed i can create a config option of `payum.action.authorize` but i have zero understanding of how twig works and absolutely not in combination of laravel.

Is there a way to gain a bit more control over the view? Or the AuthorizeAction itself?

I found that all the actions in the `KlarnaCheckoutGatewayFactory` is configurable, so i tried making a my own `AuthorizeAction` that extends from the default, and then include it in the config when adding a new gateway to payumBuilder. But i guess that's not supposed to work because i got the following error:

> LogicException in ArrayObject.php line 21:
>   Traversable interface must be implemented in case custom ArrayAccess instance given. It is because some php limitations.

Comment: If you have zero understanding of the Twig templating engine you can simply read the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation) and get acquainted with it. If you can understand Blade you will understand Twig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace payum.action.render_template with the one which support blade.  Also you have to overwrite the path to authorize  template, something that blade understands.

```
<?php
/** @var Payum $payum */
$payum = (new PayumBuilder())
    ->addDefaultStorages()
    ->addGateway('aGateway', [
        'factory' => 'klarna_checkout'
        'payum.action.render_template' => new BladeRenderTemplateAction(/* args*/),
        'payum.template.authorize' => 'path/to/blade/template',
    ])

    ->getPayum()
;
```

P.S. We can add this render template action to laravel package and made it a default one.

Comment: Thanks! I've made a pr on the LaravelPackage adding the RenderTemplateAction